# How to enable/disable TextBox according to ComboBox in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Is it possible to enable/disable TextBox according to ComboBox selected value (for example enable it if selected value is "From To"?

```
<ListView Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,92,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" 
          SelectionMode="Multiple"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <!--another columns-->
            <GridViewColumn Header="Selection Mode">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Width="70" Name="SelectionMode">
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="From To" IsSelected="True" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="List" />
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Width="70"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you use ComboBoxItem's values as opposed to content. You'll need to write a binding which will *bind* your combobox `SelectedValue` (see my suggestion) to `Enabled` of your textbox. The binding will use a converter (`IValueConverter`), which will return `True` or `False` depending on `SelectedValue` value passed in - based on your query if `SelectedValue == 'FromTo'`, your converter will return `True`, otherwise `False`.

I'd also suggest that you use objects, backing your UI elments, which is by all means a cleaner way of doing things.

Comment: It could be done more easily with a DataTrigger in the textbox's gridviewcolumn style.

Comment: @Baboon Can you please explain how to do that? Thanks